# How to Automate the AWS Data Migration Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Is there any way to schedule the DMS task at specific Time. In AWS Console I didn't find any related options.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Automating AWS DMS Migration Tasks | AWS Database Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/automating-aws-dms-migration-tasks/):

> Currently, DMS tasks cannot be scheduled using the DMS console. To
> schedule DMS tasks, we need to use the native tools present in the OS
> (Windows or Linux) that you use to access AWS resources. This blog
> post shows you how to do so.
>
> Moving forward, the process that this post describes should greatly
> simplify automated task deployments and modification scenarios.
> Following is a detailed description on how to automatically execute
> the DMS task or schedule it for execution in Linux and Windows.